# Emulate vim within Python Subprocess

Tags: python, bash, vim, terminal

I'd really like to run an instance of Vim within a subprocess so that I can control/view the input/output to the Vim instance. Right now my plan is to do something like the following:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'vim'])
```

and then pipe the output / input between the window the user is typing in and some emulated vim instance in `proc`. To make this as easy as possible I was thinking that I could make `proc` appear as similar as possible to the bash process running in the current terminal window so that I could just copy the output of the `vim` process running to some `curses` interface.

I have two questions. The first is - is there a better way to do this? The second is - if this is the best way to do it, how would I make `proc` as similar as possible to the current terminal window (e.g., keep simulated height/width of the terminal window).

Comment: I'm not good enough to answer your questions, but I think you should really explain WHY you are doing this instead of using `ex`

Comment: `ex`? I am doing this because I want to record input to a `vim` session.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record input to a `vim` session, you should simply start `vim -w file`.

```
-w {scriptout}
      All the characters that you type are recorded in the file {scriptout}, 
      until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want to create a script 
      file to be used with "vim  -s"  or  ":source!". If the {scriptout}
      file exists, characters are appended.
```